# Can't refer to create client Id dialog box

Tags: google-api, google-plus

I am following the following steps from [here](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/javascript-flow#step_1_create_a_client_id_and_client_secret). [image]

In the Step 7, they have mentioned " In the resulting `Create Client Id` dialog box, register the origins and so on...

Here is the screenshot of my `Google Developers Console` :[image]

I don't understand, where should I look for `Create Client Id` dialog box? Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

It's the big red button that says "Create new Client ID".

Comment: After clicking that button only, I got the CLIENT ID and API Key information mentioned on the right hand side of the bid red button "Create new Client ID"